# Trilead VM Explorer: Failed Transfer Error

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I am using Trilead VM Explorer to backup virtual machines on ESXi host.

When I try to perform a backup I get the following error:

> Failed: Transfer Error (The upload failed (Unable to write data to the
>   transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue with the backup, I tried to enable the agent on ESXi server. By following these steps:

- Start VM Explorer
- Switch to the "Datacenter" tab
- Rightclick your ESXi server in the "My Datacenter" list and choose "Edit Server..."
- Switch to "Expert settings" tab
- Enable the "use SSH (SCP) to transfer files if this is an ESXi host"
- The option "Try to use the VMX agent on ESXi" is also activated
- Test the connection
- if all okay save changes.

I closed VM Explorer and started it again. Now, the download and upload to ESXi will use the Agent.